# Could not open SQL database in android studio

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I am using SQL DB file for my android application which is English to English Words meaning app. I am using SQL database file for definations, my app was working good, but when i run my app on android version 8 it get crashed and it says could not open Database. Can any one help me ???

## **this is my DH Helper Class :**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private String DB_PATH = null;

    private static final String DB_NAME = "eng_dictionary.db";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;

    private final Context context;


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        this.context = context;
        this.DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";
        Log.i("DB_PATH", DB_PATH);
    }


    public void createDatabase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDatabase();

        if (!dbExist) {

            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDatabase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error Copying Database");
            }

        }

    }


    public boolean checkDatabase() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {

            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);


        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "DB Error : "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null;


    }


    private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {

        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
        int length;

        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {

            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);

        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDatabase() throws SQLException {

        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    }


    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (myDatabase != null) {
            myDatabase.close();
        }

        super.close();


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

        try {

            this.getReadableDatabase();
            context.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);
            copyDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public Cursor getMeaning(String text)
    {
        try {
            Cursor c= myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT en_definition FROM words WHERE en_word==UPPER('"+text+"')",null);
            return c;
        }catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Cursor getSuggestions(String text) {
        try {
            Cursor c = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT _id, en_word FROM words WHERE en_word LIKE '" + text + "%' LIMIT 40", null);
            return c;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }



    public void inserHistory(String text){

        try {
            myDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO history(word) VALUES('"+text+"')");
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public Cursor getHistory()
    {
        try{
            Cursor c= myDatabase.rawQuery("select distinct  word, en_definition from history h join words w on h.word==w.en_word order by h._id desc",null);
            return c;
        }catch (Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }


    public void  deleteHistory()
    {
        myDatabase.execSQL("DELETE  FROM history");
    }


}
```

## **this is my load databse class: **

```
public class LoadDatabaseAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private Context context;
    private AlertDialog alertDialog;
    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    public LoadDatabaseAsync(Context context) {

        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        AlertDialog.Builder d = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_database_copying, null);
        d.setTitle("Loading Database");
        d.setView(dialogView);
        alertDialog = d.create();
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

        try {
            databaseHelper.createDatabase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Database was not Created");
        }

        databaseHelper.close();
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        alertDialog.dismiss();
        //DashBoardActivity.Companion.openDatabase();
    }


}
```

## **in my main activity :**

```
private fun openDatabase() {
            try {
                databaseHelper!!.openDatabase()
                databaseOpenned = true
            } catch (e: SQLException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
```

## **in onCreate :**

```
databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper(this)
        if(databaseHelper!!.checkDatabase()){
            openDatabase()
        }else{
            val loadDatabaseAsync = LoadDatabaseAsync(this)
            loadDatabaseAsync.execute()
        }
```